# What is north-up projection?

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, grass-gis

How do I know what projection to use for north-up or 0 rotation? I have a gtiff (ND83-nf) that gives me the error when importing to Grass. Should I re-project or recreate the image with the rotation burned into the image? If I re-project what projection should I use? when  I re-project in fwtools the default comes up as the same as the input. not sure what to choose.
Thanks

Comment: What exactly is the text of "the error" when you import into Grass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you got the error "ERROR: Input map is rotated - cannot import." with [r.in.gdal](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/html64_user/r.in.gdal.html).

In this case the image must be first externally rotated, applying the rotation info stored in the metadata field of the raster image file. For example, the [gdalwarp](http://www.gdal.org) software can be used to transform the map to North-up (note, there are several gdalwarp parameters to select the resampling algorithm):

gdalwarp rotated.tif northup.tif

Comment: I am sorry for being so dense. I am still confused. If my image has a projection. and I use gdalwarp to transform to northup. what projection will it be in? Also in your answer there is an example command line with the command, the input, and the output (I assume). what is the parameter to make it north up? I tried the commend with no parameters and still wasn't able to load in grass.

Comment: Please post what you have done, also the gdalinfo output of the original file to better understand the situation.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be rotating your image, you will just be resampling it to a grid (raster) that is north-up. The output raster of gdalwarp is automatically resampled to a north-up raster with the projection that you have chosen with the option -t_srs.